# Can't connect to remote HBase Cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have a small HBase/Hadoop cluster.  I can login to the master server and run commands against hbase via the hbase shell without a problem.  However, when I try to do the same thing from a remote machine I get the below error:

> ERROR: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. h : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.175.224.75:6000]

I ran a netstat on the master server to confirm it was listening on port 60000 and got the following (x.x.x.x is the ip address of the master server).

> tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:60000     *:*                     LISTEN

I believe this means that the master server is only listening for connections on port 60000 that originate from itself.  Is there a way to configure HBase to accept remote connections?  Here is my hbase-site.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.master</name>
    <value>master:60000</value>
    <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.
        TODO: Support 'local' (All running in single context).
    </description>
  </property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:9000/hbase</value>
    <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>The mode the cluster will be in. Possible values are
      false: standalone and pseudo-distributed setups with managed Zookeeper
      true: fully-distributed with unmanaged Zookeeper Quorum (see hbase-env.sh)
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>localhost</value>
 </property>
  <property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/master</value>
  </property>
<property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>/home/hduser/hbase/zookeeper</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: 10.175.224.75 - that looks like a private IP address? Are you running this on Amazon's EMR service by any chance?

Comment: I'm running on windows azure. 10.175.224.75:6000 is the servers internal ip but the remote machine I'm trying connect from is on windows azure as well so I wouldn't think that would be a problem. Also, I'm referencing the public ip in all config files so I'm not sure why it's trying to connect to the internal ip.

Comment: I'm more familiar with Amazon AWS - does Azure have anything like security groups? Even though its all your machines, you might have to open up security groups to let one machine access another. The HBase ports are non-standard, so you might have to explicitly open them (like on Amazon AWS.)

Comment: Azure doesn't have security groups but it does block all ports by default. I opened port 60000 among others on the master.